# Cannot start PyCharm Cannot find VM options file (Pycharm Professional 2017.2)

Tags: pycharm

I have downloaded PyCharm Professional as per the instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/requirements-installation-and-launching.html#linux
Upon trying to start pycharm (`. pycharm.sh`) I get the error in the subject of this post.

I have manually created vmoptions file as per instructions at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties but I'm getting the same error. I've tried it with every possible variation of the name of the vmoptions file:

- pycharm.vmoptions
- pycharm64.vmoptions
- pycharm.exe.vmoptions
- pycharm64.exe.vmoptions

Still the same error occurs.

This is what gets displayed in the terminal:

```
$ ll *.vmo*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 329 Jul 29 15:48 pycharm64.exe.vmoptions
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 329 Jul 29 16:09 pycharm64.vmoptions
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 337 Jul 29 15:51 pycharm.exe.vmoptions
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 337 Jul 29 16:09 pycharm.vmoptions
$ . pycharm.sh 
bash: alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
        /usr/bin/egrep: No such file or directory 
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

And here's the dialog with the error message:
[image]

Any advice on how to diagnose this please? I should point out I'm a bit of a linux noob so may need the proverbial idiot's guide to fixing it.

Comment: Can you post the whole error messages? I think `pycharm.vmoptions` in bin directory should work.

Comment: thx for the reply. Sure, I have edited the question

Comment: Maybe try `./pycharm.sh` instead of `. pycharm.sh` because `.` is same as `source`

Comment: Oh Geez...that worked. Can't believe it was that simple!!! Told you I was a linux noob :)  Thank you @aristotll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `./pycharm.sh` instead of `. pycharm.sh` because `.` is same as `source`.